# Problem regarding sendRequest in Postman in a for loop

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing, postman-pre-request-script

I'm currently struggling with a problem regarding pm.sendRequest in Postman Pre-request script.
I'm trying to run a Request within a for loop, but something it doesn't work properly.

**Pre-request Script**

```
var numberOfCampaigns = 2; //this number can have any value from 1 to 20)
for (var j = 0; j < numberOfCampaigns; j++) {
    console.log(`J1:` + j);
  var request_call = {
    url: pm.environment.get("api-url"),
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "content-type": "text/xml",
      SOAPAction: "add",
    },
    body: {
      mode: "raw",
      raw: "some-body"},
  };
  pm.sendRequest(request_call, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      console.log(`J2:` + j);
        length = 2
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        pm.environment.set(`someVariable_` + i + `_` + j, responseJson[i]);       
        console.log(`someVariable:`+i+`_`+j+`:`+ pm.environment.get(`someVariable_` + i + `_`+j));
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(`J3:` + j);
}
```

**Console output:**

```
J1:0
J3:0
J1:1
J3:1
POST https://api-url/
J2:2
someVariable_0_2:...
someVariable_1_2:...
POST https://api-url/
J2:2
someVariable_0_2:...
someVariable_1_2:...
GET https://api-url2/ (The actual Request)
```

I don't understand why the J2 console output is 2 instead of being 1 for the first Request then 2 for the second Request

Could you please help ?

**UPDATE**

After @Keith response I tried to make some changes:

```
var numberOfCampaigns = 2

const _dummy = setInterval(() => {}, 300000 );

function sendRequest(req) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pm.sendRequest(req, (err,res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
        }
      console.log(`J2:` + j);
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
        pm.environment.set(`someVariable_` + i + `_` + j, responseJson[i]);       
        console.log(`someVariable:`+i+`_`+j+`:` + pm.environment.get(`someVariable_` + i + `_`+j));
      }
        return resolve(res);
    })
    });
}

(async function main() {
    for(var j=0; j<numberOfCampaigns; j++){
        var request_call = {
        url: pm.environment.get("api-url"),
        method: "POST",
        header: {
          "content-type": "text/xml",
          SOAPAction: "add",
        },
        body: {
          mode: "raw",
          raw: pm.environment.get(`parameter`+j},
        };
        await sendRequest(request_call);
        clearInterval(_dummy);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Add log in if(err). It might getting inside if.

Comment: Done, thank you for suggestion @NehaPatil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts are *asynchronous* - `pm.sendRequest` makes the request and calls your callback function when *that request completes*.

That may take varying amounts of time.

I would expect your script to start:

```
J1:0
J3:0
J1:1
J3:1
```

Because all of those are synchronous.

`J2:` will appear when your HTTP requests return, but by then your loop will have finished, so they will both show `J2:2`.

Note that `i` will work because it's inside your callback function, and `var j` is *global* - JS doesn't apply closures to loops or blocks unless you use `let j` and the callback would keep the reference to it anyway.

You may even get the `someVariable` logs out of order because the requests won't queue - whatever server may finish the second request before the first one.

The best way to avoid this is with `await` or [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to makes sure that your JS outside of the callback doesn't run until the async actions have finished.

Comment: I understand, but how can I implement all those request using await or Promise beacuse I'm not that expert in JS and its kinda difficult for me. I saw (https://community.postman.com/t/executing-sync-requests-programmatically-from-a-pre-request-or-test-scripts/14678/2) that I can implement, but I can't understand how can I do this in my case beacuse for me the number of sendRequest may be different for each request.

Comment: @Paracetamol12 yes, that link uses `await`, if you use it it will mean that your loop pauses (and doesn't increment) until the request finishes. `await` sounds like the best way to get your code to work, but you'll need `async` on the top level method.

Comment: ,I added an update to the original post with my changes, but I don't why It works only for the first Request then I recieve `RefferenceError: j is not defined` then Sending request is loading forever. Did I made something bad in the code ?

Comment: @Paracetamol12 yes, now `var j` is inside a function it's no longer visible to `sendRequest` - add a parameter to the function `sendRequest(req, j)` and then do `await sendRequest(request_call, j)` to pass it through.

Comment: Thank you very much @Keith, I don't know how to thank you, now everything works great, after your sugesstion and to get clearInterval(_dummy) out of from for. Thank you again